# interface components becomes hidden because of react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using 'react-native-router-flux' to navigate between Signin and Signup interfaces, 
but Router code makes the interface empty as shown :

[image: SignUp interface after using Router here]

my code for Router flux:

```
import React from 'react';

import {Router, Scene, Reducer} from 'react-native-router-flux';


import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';


const Routes = () => React$Node = () => {
  return (

    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
          <Scene
            key="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
            title="SignIn"
          />
          <Scene
            key="SignUp"
            component={SignUp}
            title="SignUp"
            initial
          />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default Routes;
```

for both sign in and sign up I add this line :

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

and

```
onPress={() => Actions.SignIn()} / onPress={() => Actions.SignUp()}
```

also I import Routes into App.js

```
 import Routes from './src/Routes';
 <Routes/>
```

I cannot figure out where is the problem cuz I'm new with react native .
hope you help me :)